# Center a view in another view

Tags: java, android

I want to to this:

```
---------------------
|                   |
|       hello       |
|                   |
---------------------
```

I want to put a TextView inside an Image view. How I can do that?
I need something like

```
paramsT.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, MAIN_TITLE_ID);
```

But instead of "ALIGN_BASELINE", something like "ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICALLY"

Thanks in advance!!! =)

Comment: please show the code that you have tried to solve this

Comment: Do you need relative layout? You can achieve this by using FrameLayout. Every child inside Framelayout overlap it's sibling. Seems like this would be your best bet (if there was no explicit need for RelativeLayout).

Comment: I have tried loads of things, but any of them have worked. I thought adding half of the height of the imageview as padding of the textview, but it is imposible to know in advance the final size of the image view.

Comment: iBecar -> thanks, I'm trying that. feedback soon, I hope :)

Comment: Can you use `SpringLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of solution : 
 -as iBecar said,you can use a framlayout, and put `android.gravity = center` to make all your views overlap and have the same center-point.

-another solution is : do you need your imageview, or could you use a Relativelayout with `android.background = "your image"` and `android.garivty = center` ?

Comment: The two solutions seems to be ok. Thanks!!! :)